# Best way to split one beamer file in several subfiles

Tags: beamer

Say you have several lectures with overlapping topics.

What is the best way to manage each topic separately and merge them together to a single lecture.

One idea (I am a newbie) is to create files that only can be inputed:

`topic1/topic1.tex`:

```
\section{Topic1}
\begin{frame}
    This is topic 1.
\end{frame}
```

`topic2/topic2.tex`:

```
\section{Topic2}
\begin{frame}
    This is topic 2.
\end{frame}
```

And then a file like `Lecture1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        Welcome to lecture 1.
    \end{frame}
    
    \input{topic1/topic1.tex}

    \input{topic2/topic2.tex}
  
\end{document}
```

Is this the most elegant way or are there other techniques in LaTeX to do so?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Probably you also want to put the preamble (or parts of it) into a separate file such that you can input it from every lecture requiring the same settings (because of shared  chapters).

Comment: Yeah, good idea!

Comment: Take a look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/1952